# Trying to display • œ, and the symbol that's like @ only with a g in C++

Tags: c++, text, unicode, codeblocks

I'm writing a small console program and trying to get it to display those characters. I have function that returns a character to be displayed based on the value passed as an argument, but can't get it to display the characters. from things I've read I've tried returning '\u2022' for bullet since that's the value I'm finding everywhere I look online, tried just copy pasting the characters into the source code, and messed around with the encoding settings in codeblocks but still haven't gotten anywhere. I've gotten an o with a ' above it but that's the closest I've come.

Can someone please explain how to do this or which number representations I should be using and where to find them?

Comment: You need to either set `std::locale::global` to your system environment locale and use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` to write wide characters to standard output, or encode this unicode character according to your system environment locale's character set, and output it to `std::cout`. Unicode is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has limited Unicode support for console input/output. Your Code::Blocks setup is likely using MingGW-32 which has additional issues. You have to use `WriteConsoleW` directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

//ελληνικά    
void myprint(const wchar_t* str)
{
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteConsoleW(h, str, wcslen(str), NULL, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    myprint(L"œ\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note, I added some Greek text in to the code to force UTF8 conversion on the *.cpp file, in order to support saving `"œ"` (by the way, Windows API actually use UTF16)

This still won't work for some Asian languages. You can also add your own `<<` operator override to make this fall in line with C++ look.